# Is it possible to set default ORACLE dblink for session and avoid @dblink_name suffixes

Tags: oracle, session, dblink

I have an Oracle database with a couple of public dblinks for various customers. All linked databases for all customers are identical. Also I have a schema on my host machine only, where I stored DB views with some data retrieval logic.
Currently, if I want to retrieve the same data from various customers, I have to create separate almost identical views for every client:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view_for_cliet1 AS 
SELECT *
FROM table1@dblink1;

CREATE VIEW my_view_for_cliet2 AS 
SELECT *
FROM table1@dblink2
```

Is it possible to set default dblink for session (or something similar) and have only one DB view without explicit dblink, for example:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view AS 
    SELECT *
    FROM table1;

-- below I want to retrieve data from 3rd client 
ALTER SESSION SET DEFAULT DBLINK dblink3;
 
SELECT * FROM my_view;
```

P.S. I have only SELECT rights on linked machines so I can't create any views or other objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not possible. Every reference to a dblink must be explicit.

Note that each of the other solutions presented (so far) can give the *appearance* of what you're asking, but still require explicit dblink references in all of the actual views and thus the same DDL changes for every new link and/or client user. There's no way to avoid creating those individual views or explicit references at some level (which is what I believe you were asking), even if you hide them somewhat from the user.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using synonyms, and set up a procedure to change them all at once, e.g.

```
create or replace procedure SET_DBLINK ( target_link IN VARCHAR2 ) is
begin
  execute immediate 'create or replace synonym TABLE1 for TABLE1@' || target_link;
  execute immediate 'create or replace synonym TABLE2 for TABLE2@' || target_link;
  -- ...etc... 
end;
/
```

That way you could do:

```
exec SET_DBLINK('dblink3');
select * from table1;
```

You'd probably want to add validation and exception handling to the procedure, but I left it simple for readability.

Comment: Thankyou! Interesting solution, I am still afraid how it will work in multithreading environment when several queries are retrieving info from different customers.. I'll will try solution and go back with experience.

Answer (score 1):

For example, user manager

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW manager.example1 (
   column1,
   column2
    )
AS
select 1, user from dual@dblink1
where 'SCOTT'=user
union all
select 2, user from dual@dblink2
where 'MANAGER'=user
union all
select 3, user from dual@dblink3
where 'HR'=user;


grant select on example1 to scott;
grant select on example1 to hr;

select * from example1;
==>
COLUMN1                                      COLUMN2                              
-------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ 
                                           2 MANAGER
```

user scott

```
create synonym example1 for manager.example1;

select * from example1;
==>
COLUMN1                                      COLUMN2                              
-------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ 
                                           1 SCOTT
```

user hr

```
create synonym example1 for manager.example1;

select * from example1;
==>
COLUMN1                                      COLUMN2                              
-------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------ 
                                           3 HR
```